# Lock two databases at the same time

Tags: mysql, mongodb, locking, database

We are moving our database server from MySQL to MongoDB for some purpose. However we observed some inconsistency data between the two servers some time after a sync, and we are investigating the problem. One thing we would like to do is to pull data from MongoDB and MySQL, and compare them. However the data is updated frequently, so we would like to lock the databases before collecting the data and compare them for a short time. Is there a possible way of locking both of them simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any explicit locking in MongoDB, but what about adding a secondary and stopping updates at a certain point in time? Then you would have a stable point for comparison without impacting the live system.

The same should be possible for MySQL with a read-only slave.